# How many bases are there in $\mathbf Z_5^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

How many bases are there in  $\mathbf Z_5^4$ ?

I've been asked to solve the above mentioned problem and had no clue how to do it. The only clear thing for me is that such base contains 4 vectors. Knowing that, I was able to count the total amount of sets which contain 4 vectors. Also I checked that we can obtain any element except 0 from $\mathbf Z_5$ by multiplying any other element by a certain scalar. For example $3*2=1$,
 $3*4=2$ ,
$3*1=3$,
$3*3=4$,
$3*5=0$, in $\mathbf Z_5$.
A base is the largest, linearly independent subset of vectors from $\mathbf Z_5^4$,so
I know that I have to combinatorially find the number of those sets, but I've no clue how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: How many choices are there for the first element in an ordered basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$ of $Z_5^4$?

Suppose now that you pick one of the possible choices $v_1$. How many choices are there for $v_2$?

Comment: I think there are 4 choices for a first element (1, 2, 3, 4). Now for the second element also 4 choices. If we go along we have the amount of 4^4 bases. But of course there are more linearly independent subsets of 4 vectors

Comment: No, there are more than $4$ choices for the first vector in the basis.

Comment: Notice that $v_1$ is not an element of $Z_5$: it is an element of $Z_5^4$, that is, a vector.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Then there have to be three zeroes and one number. We can choose this number from 1-4 and we place this number on one among four places. So the number of vectors we can get is $4*4$? Where first "4" is the number of possible places and second "4" is the count of numbers we can use?

Comment: Why there have to be three zeroes and one number? Can't $(1,1,1,1)$ be the first vector in a basis?

Comment: By the way, why did you mark my answer as accepted? You clearly did not understand it! It is better to unmark it, so that other people are more motivated to provide altenative answers. Only accept a answer when you at least know what it is saying.

Comment: All right, now I think I sorted it out. So when I am choosing the first vector in my subset I can choose from $5^4 -1$ possibilities, because I can place any number on any position except having the case with four zeroes. And that's because this (0,0,0,0) vector multiplied by any non-zero λ from field over my space will make my vectors set linearly dependent automatically. Am I right? And now, when choosing next vector, I have to choose it to make my subset linearly independent with the first vector. Are those vectors dependent only if one vector is a multiple of another?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Now, when I know the rule. For the first vector $5^4-1$. If my first vector is $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ then i cannot choose vectors $2*(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, ...,$ 4(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ and knowing that vector $5(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ is a 0, i also cannot choose him. Then it gives me $5^4-1-4$ as a second option and so on continuing to the fourth vector the count of all possible vectors I can choose is $(5^4-1)*(5^4-1 -4) *(5^4-1-4-4)*(5^4-1-4-4-4)$. Am I right?

Comment: Nope. When you choose the third vector it is not enough that it is not a linear multiple of neither the first one or the second one: it cannot be a linear combination of them either.

Comment: OK, so let's say i have chosen 2 vectors already. Now their combination might be $λ_1 v_1 + λ_2 v_2$ where $λ_1$ and $λ_2$ can be any value from 0 to 4. Then it gives 25 possibilities, which is 5^2 so third vector can be chosen in $5^4-5^2$ ways. And last vector can be chosen in $5^4-5^3$ ways, because, analogously, combination of three vectors is $λ_1 v_1 + λ_2 v_2 + λ_3 v_3 $ where $λ_1$ and $λ_2$ and $λ_3$ can be any value from 0 to 4. Then there are $(5^4-1)*(5^4-5) *(5^4-5^2)*(5^4-5^3)$ bases in $Z_5^4$.

Comment: Well, that is the number of **ordered** bases and you wanted to count unordered bases.

Comment: As I am unsure about terminology, your advice is unclear to me. If we take an ordered basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$ then are exemplary unordered bases  $(v_2,v_1,v_3,v_4) $, $(v_2,v_3,v_1,v_4)$ etc. ? Could you please give me an example of unordered base in $\mathbf Z_5^4$?

Comment: Well, a basis is a **set** of vectors, with no particular ordering. What you counted above are **ordered** sequences $(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$ such that the set $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is a basis. As you can easily see, there are several such ordered sequences which give rise to the *same* set.

Comment: Then, as there are $4!$ possibilities to write down one set which consists of four elements, would I have to divide my result by $4!$ ?

Comment: Yes. That gives you the correct number. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You know how you create a basis in a vector space: choose one vector $v_1\ne 0$, then choose another vector $v_2\not\in span(v_1)$, then choose another vector $v_3\not\in span(v_1,v_2)$ etc.

In this case: in how many ways can $v_1$ can be chosen? Then, how many elements are in $span(v_1)$, and in how many ways can you choose $v_2$? Again, how many elements are in $span(v_1, v_2)$, and in how many ways can you choose $v_3$? Finally, do the same for $v_4$.